# Get delta Mouse wheel on LWJGL3 (GLFW)

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

I'm trying to make a 3D camera around a player on a game made with LWJGL3.
With the mouse scroll wheel you'll be able to zoom on the player.
How my function should be ?

How I query every event the mousewheel value.

```java
        glfwSetScrollCallback(window.getWindowHandle(), (windowHandle, xoffset, yoffset) -> {
            currentMouseWheel.x = xoffset;
            currentMouseWheel.y = yoffset;
        });
```

My function to get Scroll delta based on the previous call :
(PS : input is called each gameLoop)

```java
    public void input(Window window) {
        dMouseWheel.x = 0;
        dMouseWheel.y = 0;
        if (inWindow) {
            double dx = currentMouseWheel.x - previousMouseWheel.x;
            double dy = currentMouseWheel.y - previousMouseWheel.y;
            if (dx != 0) {
                dMouseWheel.x = (float) dx;
            }
            if (dy != 0) {
                dMouseWheel.y = (float) dy;
            }
        }
        previousMouseWheel.x = currentMouseWheel.x;
        previousMouseWheel.y = currentMouseWheel.y;
    }
```

`xoffset` and `yoffset` are never equals to 0.

I have to make big impulse on the scrollwheel to see the delta change.

What should I do ?
Can you give me an example ?

UPDATE : I found out !
How to do it :

First of all set 2 vectors variables :

```java
private Vector2d currentMouseWheel;
private Vector2f dMouseWheel;
```

Then in your Scroll callback :

```java
glfwSetScrollCallback(window.getWindowHandle(), (windowHandle, xoffset, yoffset) -> {
 currentMouseWheel.x = xoffset;
 currentMouseWheel.y = yoffset;
});
```

Then each game loop iteration, you call a function to update it

```java
public void input() {
 dMouseWheel.x = 0;
 dMouseWheel.y = 0;

 if (inWindow) {
 dMouseWheel.x = (float) currentMouseWheel.x;
 dMouseWheel.y = (float) currentMouseWheel.y;
 }

 currentMouseWheel.x = 0;
 currentMouseWheel.y = 0;
}
```

Then you'll have dMouseWheel with the correct Scroll delta !

Comment: please separate you question and answer, makes other clear to read.

Comment: Please add you're fix as an answer so it wont be just unanswered and dead.